# Importing models in signals cause django deprecation warnings app_label

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my code in my `signals.py`

```
from .models import Entry

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Entry)
def do_stuff(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Now this questions is related

[Django 1.9 deprecation warnings app_label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635765/django-1-9-deprecation-warnings-app-label)

But I am not able to figure out why I need to create extra class for that.

```
Warning:

Model class app.models.Entry doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in
an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded.
This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
```

If I just empty my signals file then there is no warning.
The issue is using .models in signals as mentioned in that question

Comment: What is the *exact* warning you get?

Comment: I have answered the question you link to, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly likely because your application is not in the INSTALLED_APPS within your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error, what I found the error is in model import before it exist.

I used this to import model and it works for me

```
from django.apps import apps
model_obj = apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
model_obj.objects.get() ...etc
```