# RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model doesn't declare an explicit app_label

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-apps, deprecation-warning

Have gone through

[Django 1.9 deprecation warnings app_label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635765/django-1-9-deprecation-warnings-app-label)

but answers couldn't fix my problem, so asking again.

I have an app that is added to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.

when ever I run `manage.py runserver`, I get this warning,

```
[trimmed path to project]/catalog/models.py:9: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class catalog.models.Category doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class Category(models.Model):
```

The code from my app,

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from models import Category

@receiver(post_save, sender=Category)
def someSignal(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CatalogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'catalog'
    verbose_name = 'Catalogue'
```

**init.py**

```
import signals

default_app_config = 'catalog.apps.WhosConfig'
```

Django version 1.8.2 on **Python 2.7.8**

Comment: "*was imported before its application was loaded*": Your `__init__.py` imports `signals.py` which imports `models.py`. The latter thus happens before django registers the app, which is now deprecated. If you want the signals in a separate app, try to import `signals.py` from `models.py` or similar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are importing **models.py** before app configuration run.

To fix it, you could import and configure signals in `CatalogConfig.ready` method.

like this:

**signals.py**

```
def someSignal(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class CatalogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'catalog'
    verbose_name = 'Catalogue'

    def ready(self):
        from .signals import someSignal
        post_save.connect(
            receiver=someSignal,
            sender=self.get_model('Category')
        )
```

you may want to check ready method [in documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)

Answer (score 20):

I experienced this issue when running tests and it was simply a matter of changing:

```
from .models import MyModel
```

to

```
from apps.myapp.models import MyModel
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. but I don't get it. Why does the first one not work?

Comment: @whiteSkar probably because the framework was getting confused using a relative path. Instead, using an absolute path guarantees the validity of the path. This shouldn't be an issue, though.

Comment: for me I had to do `from myapp.models import MyModel` so it may depend on where you're executing tests from