# Jenkins stays forever beafore creating test database

Tags: python, django, jenkins

Jenkins never ends, it stays beafore creating the test database, the last output in the console is:

................................................................/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/7fd09b30/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py:78: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class Site(models.Model):

Why it never create the test database?

I am using Django 1.8.4 and the problem is not the warning.

Comment: which version of Django you have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model doesn't declare an explicit app\_label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179459/removedindjango19warning-model-doesnt-declare-an-explicit-app-label)

Comment: Django 1.8.4 and the problem is not the warning.