# LookupError: No installed app with label 'django_messages'

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-messages

I am trying to use https://github.com/arneb/django-messages and followed instructions as below

```
pip install django-messages

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'api',
    'localflavor',
    'django_localflavor_us',
    'django_countries',
    'haystack',
    'django_messages',

]


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^messages/', include('django_messages.urls')),
]
```

When i logged in to django shell and tried the following

```
In [1]: from django_messages.models import Message

In [2]: Message.objects.all()
Out[2]: <QuerySet []>
```

It worked fine and i can able to import Message model but when i try to register it in admin it is saying the below error

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_messages.models import Message
admin.site.register(Message)
```

Error:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 229, in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 211, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 468, in index
    app_list = self.get_app_list(request)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 451, in get_app_list
    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 431, in _build_app_dict
    'name': apps.get_app_config(app_label).verbose_name,
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'django_messages'.
```

What would be the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: No need to do that. `django_messages.Message` is already registered in admin

Comment: which version of django and django_messages ?

Comment: @itzmeontv : Its 0.5.3, my actual problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322188/runtimeerror-model-class-django-messages-models-message-doesnt-declare-an-expl/43323687#43323687, may be this was the reason i couldn't able to see it in admin

Comment: Do `import django_messages;print(django_messages.apps.DjangoMessagesConfig.name);print(django_messages.__file__)
` in shell

Comment: when i use `django_messages.apps.DjangoMessagesConfig.name` i got the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'apps'`

Comment: can you do `import django_messages;print(djan‌​go_messages.__file__‌​)`

Comment: Yeah they are working fine, `'/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/elopitch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_messages/__init__.pyc'`

Comment: do an upgrade like pip install django-messages --upgrade