# Model class myproject.apps.accounts.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm using django's `AbstractUser` to create my custom user along with my custom manager that extends `BaseUserManager`. But I didn't add any extra fields to it yet. So it looks like this:

```
# mypoject/apps/accounts/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from myproject.apps.accounts.managers import UserManager

class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager
```

And I wrote a unit test for it, and it looks like this:

```
# myproject/apps/accounts/tests/test_models.py

from unittest import TestCase

class UserTests(TestCase):
    def test_create_user(self):
        from myproject.apps.accounts.models import User
        user = User.objects.create_user(username='mock_user')
        self.assertIsInstance(user)
```

But when I run the test, I get this error message:

```
RuntimeError: Model class myproject.apps.accounts.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

PS: My accounts app is in `INSTALLED_APPS` array and works fine.

Comment: Exactly what is in INSTALLED_APPS? And what is AUTH_USER_MODEL set to?

Comment: My accounts app which contains the custom user model, is added to INSTALLED_APPS. And AUTH_USER_MODEL is set to 'accounts.User'. I even get `<class 'accounts.models.User'>` for `get_user_model()`. The problem only occurs when I explicitly import my custom User model. @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635765/django-1-9-deprecation-warnings-app-label) and to the `objects` you need to assign manager instance

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()
```